# Accessing Virtual PC from Host PC

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to setup virtual PC with php and access it from PC host ?](https://superuser.com/questions/64044/how-to-setup-virtual-pc-with-php-and-access-it-from-pc-host)

I would like to access Virtual PC URL from Host PC. I am able to access host computer from virtual PC. But not able to access the Virtual PC from Host PC.

I have tried below instruction no luck.

http://blog.flexuous.com/2007/02/04/virtual-pc-ip-routing-enabling-vpc-nat-loopback-connector-at-the-same-time/

Answer (score 0):

A virtual machine should have its own local IP address on the network.

You can run IPCONFIG in your virtual machine to get this IP address.

For example, I'm currently in a virtual machine and can see that its IP address is 192.168.2.31.  If I direct a web browser in my host machine to http://192.168.2.31:8080/ I'm successfully served the website I have bound to this port.